# Custom edit page to open as tab in console

Tags: custom-button, service-cloud-console

I have a custom edit page which is being called from a button on other vf page. Since we use console for this application I have to open the page in console as tab and on save should show the detail page.But it opens as tab with whole page like in regular application.

[image]

Here is my code for edit page:

**Page:**

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Contact" extensions="MyCustomController" id="Page" tabstyle="Contact" >

  <!-- Added for console application -->
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/30.0/integration.js"/>


<script type="text/javascript">

/* Added for console application */
   function openSubTab(url,tabLabel,isOverride) {
   // Check if user is in the Console, otherwise open as a regular URL
   var overrideTabId = null;
   if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(result){
            if(isOverride){
                overrideTabId = getCurrentTabId(); 
            }
            sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, url, true, tabLabel, overrideTabId);
        });
   } else {
        window.open(url,"_parent");
   }
  }
  function getCurrentTabId(){
    var tabId;
    sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(function(result){
                            tabId = result.id;
                        });
    return tabId;
  }


/* Added for console application ends here */

  function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
    var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
    var originalwidth = width;
    var originalmodified = modified;
    var originalsearchParam = searchParam;

    var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
    if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

    var isCustomLookup = false;

    // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account object so change this as per your standard or custom object
    if(lookupType == "001"){

      var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
      var txtId = '';
      if(urlArr.length > 2) {
        urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
        txtId = urlArr[1];
      }

      // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = "/apex/CustomAccountLKP?txt=" + txtId;

      // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
      if (modified == '1') {
        baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
      }

      // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
      if(txtId.indexOf('Account') > -1 ){
        isCustomLookup = true;
      }
    }


    if(isCustomLookup == true){
      openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    }
    else {
      if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
      openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    } 
  }
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Edit"  subtitle="New Contact" />
  <p>Contacts not associated with accounts are private and cannot be viewed by other users or included in reports.</p>
  <apex:form id="myForm">  
    <apex:PageBlock id="PageBlock" mode="Edit">  
       <apex:pageBlockButtons title="Contact Edit">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!dosavenew}" value="Save & New"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>      
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Contact Information">
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Primary_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Alternative_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!contact.AccountId}"  />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: To clarify, on save, the page behaves like a console page and you want it to behave like a standard page, is that correct? If so, would you post your controller extension?

Comment: I posted the screenshot the edit is being opened as tab but I do have all the regular salesforce stuff like sidebar and header. I want it to be just like a regular new edit page in console

Comment: It looks like it's opening as a window/tab most likely encapsulated within an I-frame (headers and all) inside the console. I recommend you look at the console API which should have instructions & code showing how to control this behavior.

Comment: Tabs in the console are iframes to begin with so that's probably not the culprit here, although I agree the toolkit API is the right way to go. @SalesforceLearner seeing the button code might help us see which URL it's navigating to and how you're opening the tab. I'd also suggest setting showHeader="false" in the VF page as a possible solution. There is some more info about how buttons in console should be done here https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2013/05/the-service-cloud-console-working-with-buttons-and-links.html